# The sure way to protect against XSS?

Tags: security, xss

I've looked through the questions and I haven't seen anyone ask this yet.

What is the for sure method to remove any sort of XSS attempts in some user submitted content? I know that `<` and `>` should be converted to `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively but I've heard mention that encoding differences can get around this too.

### Supposing a whitelist, what are all the steps to completely clean some user submitted content to ensure that no XSS vulnerabilities exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no absolute security concering XSS since people find new attack vectors every day. Sometimes XSS is even a browser bug you cant do anything about (excep some workarounds).

To get the idea of the complexity look at this (incomplete) xss attack cheat sheet.

http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Guess you should make yourself a XSS expert or hire one to reach your goal.

You can start by inspecting the attack vectors from the given link above, try to understand why it can work and make sure you prevent it.

Another great way of preventing XSS is to make sure you accept only stuff you expect instead of blocking stuff you know is bad. (i.e. whitelisting instead of blacklisting)

Answer (score 5):

http://htmlpurifier.org/ - HTMLPurifier could be of help

ps: don't create your own code, there is no way you can cover all the issues. rely on the continually developed libraries such as HTMLPurifier.

Comment: creating and using your own code is anyway never the best solution, if it comes to security...

Answer (score 3):

Old Question, but XSS isn't old, its still up to date....

So, i would recommend you to have a look for the [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and for a good overview the [OWASP XSS overview](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29)

And if you need a really good way for escaping, have a look for the [ESAPI Encoder API](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Encoder.html)

Answer (score 2):

Some of the holes I've seen fixed in different frameworks have been so unreal I don't get how they were found out. If you want to be 100% sure don't let users post content.

Answer (score 0):

Proving a negative is a difficult proposition - as googletorp points out, the only 100% solution is to not have the problem in the first place.

Functionally, the [xss attack cheat sheet at ha.ckers.org](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) is a good place to start, as is a whitelisting approach - rather than disallowing things known to be bad, only allow things known to be good.

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for a whitelist approach so I'm not sure if all the particular exploits are applicable. If I don't want to allow any HTML, Scripts or ANYTHING from the user how can I successfully turn everything the user submits into straight, harmless text content?

Answer (score 0):

**PHP-Firewall**
against XSS etc

http://www.php-firewall.info/
http://code.google.com/p/php-firewall/

```
            <?php
        /************************************************************************/
        /* PHP Firewall: Universal Firewall for WebSite                         */
        /* ============================================                         */
        /* Write by Cyril Levert                                                */
        /* Copyright (c) 2009-2010                                              */
        /* http://www.php-firewall.info                                         */
        /* dev@php-maximus.org                                                  */
        /* Others projects:                                                     */
        /* CMS PHP Maximus ( with mysql database ) www.php-maximus.org          */
        /* Blog PHP Minimus ( with mysqli database ) www.php-minimus.org        */
        /* Mini CMS PHP Nanomus ( without database ) www.php-nanomus.org        */
        /* Stop Spam Referer ( without database ) www.stop-spam-referer.info    */
        /* Twitter clone ( PHP Kweeker CMS ) www.twitter.php-minimus.org        */
        /* PHP Firewall ( without database ) www.php-firewall.info              */
        /* Personnal blog www.cyril-levert.info                                 */
        /* Release version 1.0.3                                                */
        /* Release date : 12-04-2010                                            */
        /*                                                                      */
        /* This program is free software.                                       */
        /************************************************************************/

        /** IP Protected */
        $IP_ALLOW = array();

        /** configuration define */
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_LANGUAGE', 'english' );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_ADMIN_MAIL', '' );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PUSH_MAIL', false );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_LOG_FILE', 'logs' );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_UNSET_GLOBALS', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_RANGE_IP_DENY', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_RANGE_IP_SPAM', false );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_URL', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_REQUEST_SERVER', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SANTY', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_BOTS', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_REQUEST_METHOD', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_DOS', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_UNION_SQL', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_CLICK_ATTACK', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_XSS_ATTACK', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_COOKIES', false );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_POST', false );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_GET', false );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_OVH', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_KIMSUFI', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_DEDIBOX', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_DIGICUBE', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_OVH_BY_IP', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_KIMSUFI_BY_IP', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_DEDIBOX_BY_IP', true );
        define('PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_DIGICUBE_BY_IP', true );
        /** end configuration */

        /** IPS PROTECTED */
        if ( count( $IP_ALLOW ) > 0 ) {
            if ( in_array( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $IP_ALLOW ) ) return;
        }
        /** END IPS PROTECTED */


        /** LANGUAGE */
        if ( PHP_FIREWALL_LANGUAGE === 'french' ) {
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_DEDIBOX', 'Protection contre les serveurs DEDIBOX active, cette IP range n\'est pas autorisée !');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_DEDIBOX_IP', 'Protection contre les serveurs DEDIBOX active, cette IP range n\'est pas autorisée !');

            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_DIGICUBE', 'Protection contre les serveurs DIGICUBE active, this IP range is not allowed !');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_DIGICUBE_IP', 'Protection contre les serveurs DIGICUBE active, cette IP n\'est pas autorisée !');

            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_KIMSUFI', 'Protection contre les serveurs KIMSUFI active, cette IP range n\'est pas autorisée !');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_OVH', 'Protection contre les serveurs OVH active, cette IP range n\'est pas autorisée !');

            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_BOTS', 'Attaque Bot détectée ! stop it ...');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_CLICK', 'Click attaque détectée ! stop it .....');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_DOS', 'Invalide user agent ! Stop it ...');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_OTHER_SERVER', 'Poster depuis un autre serveur est interdit !');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_REQUEST', 'Méthode de requête interdite ! Stop it ...');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_SANTY', 'Attaque Santy detectée ! Stop it ...');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_SPAM', 'Protection SPAM IPs active, cette IP range n\'est pas autorisée !');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_SPAM_IP', 'Protection SPAM IPs active, cette IP range n\'est pas autorisée !');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_UNION', 'Attaque Union détectée ! stop it ......');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_URL', 'Protection url active, string non autorisée !');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_XSS', 'Attaque XSS détectée ! stop it ...');
        } else {
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_DEDIBOX', 'Protection DEDIBOX Server active, this IP range is not allowed !');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_DEDIBOX_IP', 'Protection DEDIBOX Server active, this IP is not allowed !');

            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_DIGICUBE', 'Protection DIGICUBE Server active, this IP range is not allowed !');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_DIGICUBE_IP', 'Protection DIGICUBE Server active, this IP is not allowed !');

            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_KIMSUFI', 'Protection KIMSUFI Server active, this IP range is not allowed !');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_OVH', 'Protection OVH Server active, this IP range is not allowed !');

            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_BOTS', 'Bot attack detected ! stop it ...');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_CLICK', 'Click attack detected ! stop it .....');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_DOS', 'Invalid user agent ! Stop it ...');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_OTHER_SERVER', 'Posting from another server not allowed !');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_REQUEST', 'Invalid request method check ! Stop it ...');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_SANTY', 'Attack Santy detected ! Stop it ...');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_SPAM', 'Protection SPAM IPs active, this IP range is not allowed !');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_SPAM_IP', 'Protection died IPs active, this IP range is not allowed !');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_UNION', 'Union attack detected ! stop it ......');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_URL', 'Protection url active, string not allowed !');
            define('_PHPF_PROTECTION_XSS', 'XSS attack detected ! stop it ...');
        }
        /** END LANGUAGE*/


        if ( PHP_FIREWALL_ACTIVATION === true ) {

            FUNCTION PHP_FIREWALL_unset_globals() {
                if ( ini_get('register_globals') ) {
                    $allow = array('_ENV' => 1, '_GET' => 1, '_POST' => 1, '_COOKIE' => 1, '_FILES' => 1, '_SERVER' => 1, '_REQUEST' => 1, 'GLOBALS' => 1);
                    foreach ($GLOBALS as $key => $value) {
                        if ( ! isset( $allow[$key] ) ) unset( $GLOBALS[$key] );
                    }
                }
            }

            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_UNSET_GLOBALS === true ) PHP_FIREWALL_unset_globals();

            /** fonctions de base */
            FUNCTION PHP_FIREWALL_get_env($st_var) {
                global $HTTP_SERVER_VARS;
                if(isset($_SERVER[$st_var])) {
                    return strip_tags( $_SERVER[$st_var] );
                } elseif(isset($_ENV[$st_var])) {
                    return strip_tags( $_ENV[$st_var] );
                } elseif(isset($HTTP_SERVER_VARS[$st_var])) {
                    return strip_tags( $HTTP_SERVER_VARS[$st_var] );
                } elseif(getenv($st_var)) {
                    return strip_tags( getenv($st_var) );
                } elseif(function_exists('apache_getenv') && apache_getenv($st_var, true)) {
                    return strip_tags( apache_getenv($st_var, true) );
                }
                return '';
            }

            FUNCTION PHP_FIREWALL_get_referer() {
                if( PHP_FIREWALL_get_env('HTTP_REFERER') )
                    return PHP_FIREWALL_get_env('HTTP_REFERER');
                return 'no referer';
            }

            FUNCTION PHP_FIREWALL_get_ip() {
                if ( PHP_FIREWALL_get_env('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') ) {
                    return PHP_FIREWALL_get_env('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
                } elseif ( PHP_FIREWALL_get_env('HTTP_CLIENT_IP') ) {
                    return PHP_FIREWALL_get_env('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
                } else {
                    return PHP_FIREWALL_get_env('REMOTE_ADDR');
                }
            }
            FUNCTION PHP_FIREWALL_get_user_agent() {
                if(PHP_FIREWALL_get_env('HTTP_USER_AGENT'))
                    return PHP_FIREWALL_get_env('HTTP_USER_AGENT');
                return 'none';
            }

            FUNCTION PHP_FIREWALL_get_query_string() {
                if( PHP_FIREWALL_get_env('QUERY_STRING') )
                    return str_replace('%09', '%20', PHP_FIREWALL_get_env('QUERY_STRING'));
                return '';
            }
            FUNCTION PHP_FIREWALL_get_request_method() {
                if(PHP_FIREWALL_get_env('REQUEST_METHOD'))
                    return PHP_FIREWALL_get_env('REQUEST_METHOD');
                return 'none';
            }
            FUNCTION PHP_FIREWALL_gethostbyaddr() {
                if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_OVH === true OR PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_KIMSUFI === true OR PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_DEDIBOX === true OR PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_DIGICUBE === true ) {
                    if ( @ empty( $_SESSION['PHP_FIREWALL_gethostbyaddr'] ) ) {
                        return $_SESSION['PHP_FIREWALL_gethostbyaddr'] = @gethostbyaddr( PHP_FIREWALL_get_ip() );
                    } else {
                        return strip_tags( $_SESSION['PHP_FIREWALL_gethostbyaddr'] );
                    }
                }
            }

            /** bases define */
            define('PHP_FIREWALL_GET_QUERY_STRING', strtolower( PHP_FIREWALL_get_query_string() ) );
            define('PHP_FIREWALL_USER_AGENT', PHP_FIREWALL_get_user_agent() );
            define('PHP_FIREWALL_GET_IP', PHP_FIREWALL_get_ip() );
            define('PHP_FIREWALL_GET_HOST', PHP_FIREWALL_gethostbyaddr() );
            define('PHP_FIREWALL_GET_REFERER', PHP_FIREWALL_get_referer() );
            define('PHP_FIREWALL_GET_REQUEST_METHOD', PHP_FIREWALL_get_request_method() );
            define('PHP_FIREWALL_REGEX_UNION','#\w?\s?union\s\w*?\s?(select|all|distinct|insert|update|drop|delete)#is');
            FUNCTION PHP_FIREWALL_push_email( $subject, $msg ) {
                $headers = "From: PHP Firewall: ".PHP_FIREWALL_ADMIN_MAIL." <".PHP_FIREWALL_ADMIN_MAIL.">\r\n"
                    ."Reply-To: ".PHP_FIREWALL_ADMIN_MAIL."\r\n"
                    ."Priority: urgent\r\n"
                    ."Importance: High\r\n"
                    ."Precedence: special-delivery\r\n"
                    ."Organization: PHP Firewall\r\n"
                    ."MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
                    ."Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
                    ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n"
                    ."X-Priority: 1\r\n"
                    ."X-MSMail-Priority: High\r\n"
                    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() ."\r\n"
                    ."X-PHPFirewall: 1.0 by PHPFirewall\r\n"
                    ."Date:" . date("D, d M Y H:s:i") . " +0100\n";
                if ( PHP_FIREWALL_ADMIN_MAIL != '' )
                    @mail( PHP_FIREWALL_ADMIN_MAIL, $subject, $msg, $headers );
            }

            FUNCTION PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( $type ) {
                $f = fopen( dirname(__FILE__).'/'.PHP_FIREWALL_LOG_FILE.'.txt', 'a');
                $msg = date('j-m-Y H:i:s')." | $type | IP: ".PHP_FIREWALL_GET_IP." ] | DNS: ".gethostbyaddr(PHP_FIREWALL_GET_IP)." | Agent: ".PHP_FIREWALL_USER_AGENT." | URL: ".PHP_FIREWALL_REQUEST_URI." | Referer: ".PHP_FIREWALL_GET_REFERER."\n\n";
                fputs($f, $msg);
                fclose($f);
                if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PUSH_MAIL === true ) {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_push_email( 'Alert PHP Firewall '.strip_tags( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ) , "PHP Firewall logs of ".strip_tags( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] )."\n".str_replace('|', "\n", $msg ) );
                }
            }

            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_OVH === true ) {
                if ( stristr( PHP_FIREWALL_GET_HOST ,'ovh') ) {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'OVH Server list' );
                    die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_OVH );
                }
            }

            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_OVH_BY_IP === true ) {
                $ip = explode('.', PHP_FIREWALL_GET_IP );
                if ( $ip[0].'.'.$ip[1] == '87.98' or  $ip[0].'.'.$ip[1] == '91.121' or  $ip[0].'.'.$ip[1] == '94.23' or $ip[0].'.'.$ip[1] == '213.186' or  $ip[0].'.'.$ip[1] == '213.251' ) {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'OVH Server IP' );
                    die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_OVH );
                }
            }

            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_KIMSUFI === true ) {
                if ( stristr( PHP_FIREWALL_GET_HOST ,'kimsufi') ) {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'KIMSUFI Server list' );
                    die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_KIMSUFI );
                }
            }

            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_DEDIBOX === true ) {
                if ( stristr( PHP_FIREWALL_GET_HOST ,'dedibox') ) {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'DEDIBOX Server list' );
                    die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_DEDIBOX );
                }
            }

            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_DEDIBOX_BY_IP === true ) {
                $ip = explode('.', PHP_FIREWALL_GET_IP );
                if ( $ip[0].'.'.$ip[1] == '88.191' ) {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'DEDIBOX Server IP' );
                    die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_DEDIBOX_IP );
                }
            }

            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_DIGICUBE === true ) {
                if ( stristr( PHP_FIREWALL_GET_HOST ,'digicube') ) {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'DIGICUBE Server list' );
                    die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_DIGICUBE );
                }
            }

            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SERVER_DIGICUBE_BY_IP === true ) {
                $ip = explode('.', PHP_FIREWALL_GET_IP );
                if ( $ip[0].'.'.$ip[1] == '95.130' ) {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'DIGICUBE Server IP' );
                    die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_DIGICUBE_IP );
                }
            }

            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_RANGE_IP_SPAM === true ) {
                $ip_array = array('24', '186', '189', '190', '200', '201', '202', '209', '212', '213', '217', '222' );
                $range_ip = explode('.', PHP_FIREWALL_GET_IP );
                if ( in_array( $range_ip[0], $ip_array ) ) {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'IPs Spam list' );
                    die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_SPAM );
                }
            }

            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_RANGE_IP_DENY === true ) {
                $ip_array = array('0', '1', '2', '5', '10', '14', '23', '27', '31', '36', '37', '39', '42', '46', '49', '50', '100', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '106', '107', '114', '172', '176', '177', '179', '181', '185', '192', '223', '224' );
                $range_ip = explode('.', PHP_FIREWALL_GET_IP );
                if ( in_array( $range_ip[0], $ip_array ) ) {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'IPs reserved list' );
                    die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_SPAM_IP );
                }
            }

            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_COOKIES === true ) {
                $ct_rules = Array('applet', 'base', 'bgsound', 'blink', 'embed', 'expression', 'frame', 'javascript', 'layer', 'link', 'meta', 'object', 'onabort', 'onactivate', 'onafterprint', 'onafterupdate', 'onbeforeactivate', 'onbeforecopy', 'onbeforecut', 'onbeforedeactivate', 'onbeforeeditfocus', 'onbeforepaste', 'onbeforeprint', 'onbeforeunload', 'onbeforeupdate', 'onblur', 'onbounce', 'oncellchange', 'onchange', 'onclick', 'oncontextmenu', 'oncontrolselect', 'oncopy', 'oncut', 'ondataavailable', 'ondatasetchanged', 'ondatasetcomplete', 'ondblclick', 'ondeactivate', 'ondrag', 'ondragend', 'ondragenter', 'ondragleave', 'ondragover', 'ondragstart', 'ondrop', 'onerror', 'onerrorupdate', 'onfilterchange', 'onfinish', 'onfocus', 'onfocusin', 'onfocusout', 'onhelp', 'onkeydown', 'onkeypress', 'onkeyup', 'onlayoutcomplete', 'onload', 'onlosecapture', 'onmousedown', 'onmouseenter', 'onmouseleave', 'onmousemove', 'onmouseout', 'onmouseover', 'onmouseup', 'onmousewheel', 'onmove', 'onmoveend', 'onmovestart', 'onpaste', 'onpropertychange', 'onreadystatechange', 'onreset', 'onresize', 'onresizeend', 'onresizestart', 'onrowenter', 'onrowexit', 'onrowsdelete', 'onrowsinserted', 'onscroll', 'onselect', 'onselectionchange', 'onselectstart', 'onstart', 'onstop', 'onsubmit', 'onunload', 'script', 'style', 'title', 'vbscript', 'xml');
                if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_COOKIES === true ) {
                    foreach($_COOKIE as $value) {
                        $check = str_replace($ct_rules, '*', $value);
                        if( $value != $check ) {
                            PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'Cookie protect' );
                            unset( $value );
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_POST === true ) {
                    foreach( $_POST as $value ) {
                        $check = str_replace($ct_rules, '*', $value);
                        if( $value != $check ) {
                            PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'POST protect' );
                            unset( $value );
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_GET === true ) {
                    foreach( $_GET as $value ) {
                        $check = str_replace($ct_rules, '*', $value);
                        if( $value != $check ) {
                            PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'GET protect' );
                            unset( $value );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            /** protection de l'url */
            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_URL === true ) {
                $ct_rules = array( 'absolute_path', 'ad_click', 'alert(', 'alert%20', ' and ', 'basepath', 'bash_history', '.bash_history', 'cgi-', 'chmod(', 'chmod%20', '%20chmod', 'chmod=', 'chown%20', 'chgrp%20', 'chown(', '/chown', 'chgrp(', 'chr(', 'chr=', 'chr%20', '%20chr', 'chunked', 'cookie=', 'cmd', 'cmd=', '%20cmd', 'cmd%20', '.conf', 'configdir', 'config.php', 'cp%20', '%20cp', 'cp(', 'diff%20', 'dat?', 'db_mysql.inc', 'document.location', 'document.cookie', 'drop%20', 'echr(', '%20echr', 'echr%20', 'echr=', '}else{', '.eml', 'esystem(', 'esystem%20', '.exe',  'exploit', 'file\://', 'fopen', 'fwrite', '~ftp', 'ftp:', 'ftp.exe', 'getenv', '%20getenv', 'getenv%20', 'getenv(', 'grep%20', '_global', 'global_', 'global[', 'http:', '_globals', 'globals_', 'globals[', 'grep(', 'g\+\+', 'halt%20', '.history', '?hl=', '.htpasswd', 'http_', 'http-equiv', 'http/1.', 'http_php', 'http_user_agent', 'http_host', '&icq', 'if{', 'if%20{', 'img src', 'img%20src', '.inc.php', '.inc', 'insert%20into', 'ISO-8859-1', 'ISO-', 'javascript\://', '.jsp', '.js', 'kill%20', 'kill(', 'killall', '%20like', 'like%20', 'locate%20', 'locate(', 'lsof%20', 'mdir%20', '%20mdir', 'mdir(', 'mcd%20', 'motd%20', 'mrd%20', 'rm%20', '%20mcd', '%20mrd', 'mcd(', 'mrd(', 'mcd=', 'mod_gzip_status', 'modules/', 'mrd=', 'mv%20', 'nc.exe', 'new_password', 'nigga(', '%20nigga', 'nigga%20', '~nobody', 'org.apache', '+outfile+', '%20outfile%20', '*/outfile/*',' outfile ','outfile', 'password=', 'passwd%20', '%20passwd', 'passwd(', 'phpadmin', 'perl%20', '/perl', 'phpbb_root_path','*/phpbb_root_path/*','p0hh', 'ping%20', '.pl', 'powerdown%20', 'rm(', '%20rm', 'rmdir%20', 'mv(', 'rmdir(', 'phpinfo()', '<?php', 'reboot%20', '/robot.txt' , '~root', 'root_path', 'rush=', '%20and%20', '%20xorg%20', '%20rush', 'rush%20', 'secure_site, ok', 'select%20', 'select from', 'select%20from', '_server', 'server_', 'server[', 'server-info', 'server-status', 'servlet', 'sql=', '<script', '<script>', '</script','script>','/script', 'switch{','switch%20{', '.system', 'system(', 'telnet%20', 'traceroute%20', '.txt', 'union%20', '%20union', 'union(', 'union=', 'vi(', 'vi%20', 'wget', 'wget%20', '%20wget', 'wget(', 'window.open', 'wwwacl', ' xor ', 'xp_enumdsn', 'xp_availablemedia', 'xp_filelist', 'xp_cmdshell', '$_request', '$_get', '$request', '$get',  '&aim', '/etc/password','/etc/shadow', '/etc/groups', '/etc/gshadow', '/bin/ps', 'uname\x20-a', '/usr/bin/id', '/bin/echo', '/bin/kill', '/bin/', '/chgrp', '/usr/bin', 'bin/python', 'bin/tclsh', 'bin/nasm', '/usr/x11r6/bin/xterm', '/bin/mail', '/etc/passwd', '/home/ftp', '/home/www', '/servlet/con', '?>', '.txt');
                $check = str_replace($ct_rules, '*', PHP_FIREWALL_GET_QUERY_STRING );
                if( PHP_FIREWALL_GET_QUERY_STRING != $check ) {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'URL protect' );
                    die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_URL );
                }
            }

            /** Posting from other servers in not allowed */
            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_REQUEST_SERVER === true ) {
                if ( PHP_FIREWALL_GET_REQUEST_METHOD == 'POST' ) {
                    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
                        if ( ! stripos( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0 ) ) {
                            PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'Posting another server' );
                            die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_OTHER_SERVER );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            /** protection contre le vers santy */
            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_SANTY === true ) {
                $ct_rules = array('rush','highlight=%','perl','chr(','pillar','visualcoder','sess_');
                $check = str_replace($ct_rules, '*', strtolower(PHP_FIREWALL_REQUEST_URI) );
                if( strtolower(PHP_FIREWALL_REQUEST_URI) != $check ) {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'Santy' );
                    die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_SANTY );
                }
            }

            /** protection bots */
            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_BOTS === true ) {
                $ct_rules = array( '@nonymouse', 'addresses.com', 'ideography.co.uk', 'adsarobot', 'ah-ha', 'aktuelles', 'alexibot', 'almaden', 'amzn_assoc', 'anarchie', 'art-online', 'aspseek', 'assort', 'asterias', 'attach', 'atomz', 'atspider', 'autoemailspider', 'backweb', 'backdoorbot', 'bandit', 'batchftp', 'bdfetch', 'big.brother', 'black.hole', 'blackwidow', 'blowfish', 'bmclient', 'boston project', 'botalot', 'bravobrian', 'buddy', 'bullseye', 'bumblebee ', 'builtbottough', 'bunnyslippers', 'capture', 'cegbfeieh', 'cherrypicker', 'cheesebot', 'chinaclaw', 'cicc', 'civa', 'clipping', 'collage', 'collector', 'copyrightcheck', 'cosmos', 'crescent', 'custo', 'cyberalert', 'deweb', 'diagem', 'digger', 'digimarc', 'diibot', 'directupdate', 'disco', 'dittospyder', 'download accelerator', 'download demon', 'download wonder', 'downloader', 'drip', 'dsurf', 'dts agent', 'dts.agent', 'easydl', 'ecatch', 'echo extense', 'efp@gmx.net', 'eirgrabber', 'elitesys', 'emailsiphon', 'emailwolf', 'envidiosos', 'erocrawler', 'esirover', 'express webpictures', 'extrac', 'eyenetie', 'fastlwspider', 'favorg', 'favorites sweeper', 'fezhead', 'filehound', 'filepack.superbr.org', 'flashget', 'flickbot', 'fluffy', 'frontpage', 'foobot', 'galaxyBot', 'generic', 'getbot ', 'getleft', 'getright', 'getsmart', 'geturl', 'getweb', 'gigabaz', 'girafabot', 'go-ahead-got-it', 'go!zilla', 'gornker', 'grabber', 'grabnet', 'grafula', 'green research', 'harvest', 'havindex', 'hhjhj@yahoo', 'hloader', 'hmview', 'homepagesearch', 'htmlparser', 'hulud', 'http agent', 'httpconnect', 'httpdown', 'http generic', 'httplib', 'httrack', 'humanlinks', 'ia_archiver', 'iaea', 'ibm_planetwide', 'image stripper', 'image sucker', 'imagefetch', 'incywincy', 'indy', 'infonavirobot', 'informant', 'interget', 'internet explore', 'infospiders',  'internet ninja', 'internetlinkagent', 'interneteseer.com', 'ipiumbot', 'iria', 'irvine', 'jbh', 'jeeves', 'jennybot', 'jetcar', 'joc web spider', 'jpeg hunt', 'justview', 'kapere', 'kdd explorer', 'kenjin.spider', 'keyword.density', 'kwebget', 'lachesis', 'larbin',  'laurion(dot)com', 'leechftp', 'lexibot', 'lftp', 'libweb', 'links aromatized', 'linkscan', 'link*sleuth', 'linkwalker', 'libwww', 'lightningdownload', 'likse', 'lwp','mac finder', 'mag-net', 'magnet', 'marcopolo', 'mass', 'mata.hari', 'mcspider', 'memoweb', 'microsoft url control', 'microsoft.url', 'midown', 'miixpc', 'minibot', 'mirror', 'missigua', 'mister.pix', 'mmmtocrawl', 'moget', 'mozilla/2', 'mozilla/3.mozilla/2.01', 'mozilla.*newt', 'multithreaddb', 'munky', 'msproxy', 'nationaldirectory', 'naverrobot', 'navroad', 'nearsite', 'netants', 'netcarta', 'netcraft', 'netfactual', 'netmechanic', 'netprospector', 'netresearchserver', 'netspider', 'net vampire', 'newt', 'netzip', 'nicerspro', 'npbot', 'octopus', 'offline.explorer', 'offline explorer', 'offline navigator', 'opaL', 'openfind', 'opentextsitecrawler', 'orangebot', 'packrat', 'papa foto', 'pagegrabber', 'pavuk', 'pbwf', 'pcbrowser', 'personapilot', 'pingalink', 'pockey', 'program shareware', 'propowerbot/2.14', 'prowebwalker', 'proxy', 'psbot', 'psurf', 'puf', 'pushsite', 'pump', 'qrva', 'quepasacreep', 'queryn.metasearch', 'realdownload', 'reaper', 'recorder', 'reget', 'replacer', 'repomonkey', 'rma', 'robozilla', 'rover', 'rpt-httpclient', 'rsync', 'rush=', 'searchexpress', 'searchhippo', 'searchterms.it', 'second street research', 'seeker', 'shai', 'sitecheck', 'sitemapper', 'sitesnagger', 'slysearch', 'smartdownload', 'snagger', 'spacebison', 'spankbot', 'spanner', 'spegla', 'spiderbot', 'spiderengine', 'sqworm', 'ssearcher100', 'star downloader', 'stripper', 'sucker', 'superbot', 'surfwalker', 'superhttp', 'surfbot', 'surveybot', 'suzuran', 'sweeper', 'szukacz/1.4', 'tarspider', 'takeout', 'teleport', 'telesoft', 'templeton', 'the.intraformant', 'thenomad', 'tighttwatbot', 'titan', 'tocrawl/urldispatcher','toolpak', 'traffixer', 'true_robot', 'turingos', 'turnitinbot', 'tv33_mercator', 'uiowacrawler', 'urldispatcherlll', 'url_spider_pro', 'urly.warning ', 'utilmind', 'vacuum', 'vagabondo', 'vayala', 'vci', 'visualcoders', 'visibilitygap', 'vobsub', 'voideye', 'vspider', 'w3mir', 'webauto', 'webbandit', 'web.by.mail', 'webcapture', 'webcatcher', 'webclipping', 'webcollage', 'webcopier', 'webcopy', 'webcraft@bea', 'web data extractor', 'webdav', 'webdevil', 'webdownloader', 'webdup', 'webenhancer', 'webfetch', 'webgo', 'webhook', 'web.image.collector', 'web image collector', 'webinator', 'webleacher', 'webmasters', 'webmasterworldforumbot', 'webminer', 'webmirror', 'webmole', 'webreaper', 'websauger', 'websaver', 'website.quester', 'website quester', 'websnake', 'websucker', 'web sucker', 'webster', 'webreaper', 'webstripper', 'webvac', 'webwalk', 'webweasel', 'webzip', 'wget', 'widow', 'wisebot', 'whizbang', 'whostalking', 'wonder', 'wumpus', 'wweb', 'www-collector-e', 'wwwoffle', 'wysigot', 'xaldon', 'xenu', 'xget', 'x-tractor', 'zeus' );
                $check = str_replace($ct_rules, '*', strtolower(PHP_FIREWALL_USER_AGENT) );
                if( strtolower(PHP_FIREWALL_USER_AGENT) != $check ) {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'Bots attack' );
                    die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_BOTS );
                }
            }

            /** Invalid request method check */
            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_REQUEST_METHOD === true ) {
                if(strtolower(PHP_FIREWALL_GET_REQUEST_METHOD)!='get' AND strtolower(PHP_FIREWALL_GET_REQUEST_METHOD)!='head' AND strtolower(PHP_FIREWALL_GET_REQUEST_METHOD)!='post' AND strtolower(PHP_FIREWALL_GET_REQUEST_METHOD)!='put') {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'Invalid request' );
                    die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_REQUEST );
                }
            }

            /** protection dos attaque */
            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_DOS === true ) {
                if ( !defined('PHP_FIREWALL_USER_AGENT')  || PHP_FIREWALL_USER_AGENT == '-' ) {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'Dos attack' );
                    die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_DOS );
                }
            }

            /** protection union sql attaque */
            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_UNION_SQL === true ) {
                $stop = 0;
                $ct_rules = array( '*/from/*', '*/insert/*', '+into+', '%20into%20', '*/into/*', ' into ', 'into', '*/limit/*', 'not123exists*', '*/radminsuper/*', '*/select/*', '+select+', '%20select%20', ' select ',  '+union+', '%20union%20', '*/union/*', ' union ', '*/update/*', '*/where/*' );
                $check    = str_replace($ct_rules, '*', PHP_FIREWALL_GET_QUERY_STRING );
                if( PHP_FIREWALL_GET_QUERY_STRING != $check ) $stop++;
                if (preg_match(PHP_FIREWALL_REGEX_UNION, PHP_FIREWALL_GET_QUERY_STRING)) $stop++;
                if (preg_match('/([OdWo5NIbpuU4V2iJT0n]{5}) /', rawurldecode( PHP_FIREWALL_GET_QUERY_STRING ))) $stop++;
                if (strstr(rawurldecode( PHP_FIREWALL_GET_QUERY_STRING ) ,'*')) $stop++;
                if ( !empty( $stop ) ) {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'Union attack' );
                    die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_UNION );
                }
            }

            /** protection click attack */
            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_CLICK_ATTACK === true ) {
                $ct_rules = array( '/*', 'c2nyaxb0', '/*' );
                if( PHP_FIREWALL_GET_QUERY_STRING != str_replace($ct_rules, '*', PHP_FIREWALL_GET_QUERY_STRING ) ) {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'Click attack' );
                    die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_CLICK );
                }
            }

            /** protection XSS attack */
            if ( PHP_FIREWALL_PROTECTION_XSS_ATTACK === true ) {
                $ct_rules = array( 'http\:\/\/', 'https\:\/\/', 'cmd=', '&cmd', 'exec', 'concat', './', '../',  'http:', 'h%20ttp:', 'ht%20tp:', 'htt%20p:', 'http%20:', 'https:', 'h%20ttps:', 'ht%20tps:', 'htt%20ps:', 'http%20s:', 'https%20:', 'ftp:', 'f%20tp:', 'ft%20p:', 'ftp%20:', 'ftps:', 'f%20tps:', 'ft%20ps:', 'ftp%20s:', 'ftps%20:', '.php?url=' );
                $check    = str_replace($ct_rules, '*', PHP_FIREWALL_GET_QUERY_STRING );
                if( PHP_FIREWALL_GET_QUERY_STRING != $check ) {
                    PHP_FIREWALL_LOGS( 'XSS attack' );
                    die( _PHPF_PROTECTION_XSS );
                }
            }

        }
```